# Juju 2 generating "no current controller, and none specified error"

Tags: juju

I am very new to Juju 2 so this might be an error in how to use Juju 2. After bootstrapping, I just want to get the status of my model. So I did the following

```
$ juju status -m test-model
error: setting model name: no current controller, and none specified
```

Not sure why I am getting the error mentioned above?

Comment: That error is output when you don't have a controller running or specified. Can you update your question with the command you used to bootstrap your model and then the output from `juju list-controllers` and `juju list-models`